# Creating a ModelForm for a Modified User Auth django

Tags: django, forms, model

I have the following code:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs ={ 'id':'email'}), required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'id':'fname'}), required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'id':'lname'}), required=True)
    linked_id = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(attrs = {'id':'linkedid'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_('Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_('Re-Enter your password'), widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:

        model = UserProfile

        fields = ('email', 'first_name', ... (other fields here))

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The passwords you entered did not match!"))
        return password2
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a modified user registration form. And the form actually shows up, which is good. But If a user tries to actually register. Not all the information gets stored in my database. Only the first name and the email get saved...

EDIT::::::

sorry guys, I got it working for the most part, the fields part wasn't set up correctly. But i'm running into one other issue. When I'm viewing a test user on my site, it's not encrypting the password, its just showing the password. How do I get it to encrypt like how it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you reread the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). If you have the problem with understanding how it works you will have to look at the source.

Here is how you create a password field with a label.

```
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'input_text'}), label='Password')
```

Goodluck.

Comment: Ya, i checked them out, I actually got most of it working, lol. But I'm having an issue with the password saving. It's saving the password, literally. Normally, when it saves passwords, it encrypts it so I can't view it in the admin page. How do I get it to encrypt it again?

Comment: @de1337ed you need to use a https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput

Comment: Isn't having as a widget enough? (as shown above) I've done my current way before and it worked back then. But it's not working now. The issue is that if i set it to be a password input, then i can't put arguments in the parenthesis like "label" etc.